# Brew bash autocompletion

Tags: bash, high-sierra, homebrew

I just installed bash 4.4.19 through brew on my mac and configured Terminal.app to use it as the default shell. All of that works.

Now when I type `ln -s $HOME/`+<kbd>TAB</kbd> it gets autocompleted to `ln -s \$HOME/`. The default bash that comes with macOS 10.13 would instead auto-complete that to `ln -s /Users/lars/`.

How can I get the old behavior back so that `$HOME` auto-completes to my home directory?

Comment: what are the benefits of bash 4.4.19?

Comment: I wanted to glob recursively with `**/*`, which is possible with shopt globstar, which was not available in the stock bash that came with high sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding the following to my `.bash_profile`

```
shopt -s direxpand
complete -r cd
```